# Insert scroll button horizontal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to replicate this [example](https://codepen.io/pen88pen/pen/vYdBxMy) into my own [coding](https://codepen.io/pen88pen/pen/eYVOveP).

The `List` tabs are generated dynamically using JS and each have their table (also generated using JS). Unfortunately, there is a problem where the button won't show even after resizing the screen. I couldn't find anything that I missed out though.

And another problem is that when reload, sometimes there is an error at line `$('.nav-item').last().offset().left` eventhough I already load the `reAdjust()` function in `$( document ).ready(function()`.

Comment: This is really difficult to answer, but maybe this will help inspire you, a similar horizontal scroll function: https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/dyJjNEP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue where there are other classes with the same name `list` which is why the button won't show up properly.